# AWS Athena Create Table with JSON

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to create a table with this below data value:

```
{"name": "Tommy", "Age": 16, "date":{"string": "2020-10-10"}} 
{"name": "Will", "Age": 20, "date":{"string": "2020-10-10"}}
```

but when I try to access data from a select it comes:
{"string":"2020-10-10"}
and I just need data value

there is any option to solve this on create table step? For exemple, to create a table looking to the date["string"] value.

I know, this is very specific, but if someone knows I'll be very happy! Thks

Comment: you have to select the columns and pass them to CTAS for creating table so that you can see values only.

Comment: When you say "data value" do you mean "date value"?

Answer (score 1):

One common way to solve this kind of situation is to use a view. Assuming you have a table called `nested_Data` with `name`, `age`, and `date` columns where the date column is defined as `struct<string:string>`, you can create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW flat_data AS
SELECT name, age, date['string'] AS date
FROM nested_data
```

when you run a query like `SELECT date FROM flat_data` you will get only the date value.

Views are often used like this when the raw data needs a bit of pre-processing and you want to avoid having to include all that pre-processing in every query.